# Maven minify tool configuration

Tags: maven, minify

I am using `minify-maven-plugin` tool to minify the `js` and `css` files in my project. The configuration is as shown below.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <warSourceExcludes>**/*.css, **/*.js</warSourceExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-minify</id>
                <configuration>
                    <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                    <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                    <webappSourceDir>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webappSourceDir>
                    <cssSourceDir>resources/public/css</cssSourceDir>
                    <jsSourceDir>resources/public/js</jsSourceDir>
                    <cssSourceFiles>
                        <cssSourceFile>bootstrap-select.css</cssSourceFile>
                        <cssSourceFile>bootstrap-switch.css</cssSourceFile>
                    </cssSourceFiles>
                    <jsSourceFiles>
                        <jsSourceFile>bootbox.js</jsSourceFile>
                        <jsSourceFile>bootstrap-select.js</jsSourceFile>
                    </jsSourceFiles>
                    <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                    <closureCreateSourceMap>true</closureCreateSourceMap>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>minify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

When I run the command `mvn clean compile package` with the above `pom.xml`, the `war` file gets generated.

I deploy the `war` file to the server which is on Amazon EC2 instance.

When I access the `js` files on the browser after the deployment, I can see the files are minified too, but failing to load the `css` and `js` files!

But if I comment the line from the above `pom.xml`,

```
<configuration>
    <warSourceExcludes>**/*.css, **/*.js</warSourceExcludes>
</configuration>
```

then, everything works fine, but the files are not minified.

What is that thing I am doing wrong in this configuration?

Comment: Just a hint: `mvn ... compile package` isn't necessary, `mvn ... package`is sufficient, since _all_ phases up to and including the given phase are passed every time anyway. See [Maven/ Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Thanks Gerold Broser, that still did not resolve my problem.
I see that it is a problem with the configuration of maven-war-plugin where I am doing something wrong.

Comment: maybe the `css` and `js` files are deployed to the wrong position in the directory structure? Please show the directory structure. I'm not familar with this plugin, but I faced similar issues using other plugins which handle resources

Comment: Thanks Ulrich for your response. Fortunately, I figured out that I had not included all the js and css files for minifying.